# how can i populate the value of dropdownbox while selecting the value of another website in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdown box one for country and second for states

what i should do ?  I would select the country from the first dropdown box and

second dropdown box should be filled up with name of the states of concerned country

i want to use jquery and PHP

states and countries are stored in mysql database

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display DB contents after selecting a dropdown list option using PHP, AJAX and MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623031/how-can-i-display-db-contents-after-selecting-a-dropdown-list-option-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

How to do dynamic dependent select box using Jquery, Ajax, PHP and Mysql. Dependent select box when a selection is made in a "Parent" box it allow to refresh a "child" box list data.

http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html

Answer (score 0):

The below code will be triggered when the selected value of your country drop down list changes.

You could then use a PHP script to return a JSON list of states which will then be populated into your states drop down list.

```
$('#IdOfYourCountryList').change(function(){

    var country = $(this);

    $.getJSON("UrlOfYourPHPScript", function(result) {

        $.each(result, function() {
            options.append($("<option />").val(this.Value).text(this.Key));
        });

    });

});
```

`this.Key` and `this.Value` refer to the name and value you want for each option, the names may change based on how you structure the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Tones of examples of this kind of thing.  Google is your friend.  Here's one example:
http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html