# Zend - combobox value depending on another combobox value

Tags: php, zend-framework, combobox, zend-form, zend-studio

Is there a way in Zend Framework to fill a combobox with values depending on the value chosen in a previous combobox, but on the same page?

In my case I have a combobox for domain and one for specialization. If i choose Informatics in the first combobox (domain), I want to fill the second one with a single specialization - "Informatics". But if I choose Math in the first, I want to fill the second one with two specialization: "Mathematics" and "Mathematics & Informatics".

Thank you!
Sorin

Comment: Have you tried AJAX? when one of the combo boxes changes do an AJAX request to the server and return a json object containing the option for the second combo box.

Comment: Possible Dupe of [how can i populate the value of dropdownbox while selecting the value of another website in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546883/how-can-i-populate-the-value-of-dropdownbox-while-selecting-the-value-of-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a very simple solution: I've put the option to choose the domain on one page and the option to choose the specialization on another page, based on the domain chosen.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the data with relationships between domain and specialisation in a database in your server. you can attach a listener on change event to your domain combo box and fill the second combo box accordingly by retrieving specialisations of the selected domain using an ajax post request :

here's an example using jquery :

```
 $(".domain").change(function()
{
  var domainId=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'domainId='+ domainId; 

 $.ajax
 ({
   type: "POST",
   url: baseurl+"getSpecialisations", 
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
          {
            $(".specialisation").html(html);
          }
 });
});
```

and in your controller create an action getSpecialisationsAction that will retrieve your domain's specifications, check [here](http://blog.ekini.net/2007/08/28/jquery-ajax-in-zend-framework/) for an example of how to send post request to a zend action .